# Solving Trigonometric Equations in wxMaxima

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I am new in wxmaxima and i try to learn how can i solve trigonometric equations.
Can you help me with the sample program ? for example
`Sin(X)+Cos(Y) = sqrt(3)`
`Sin(X)*Cos(Y) = 3/4`
How can i get X,Y [0,2*pi] ?

Comment: Note that sine and cosine functions are written `sin` and `cos` in Maxima (small initial letters). The function `solve` can solve some equations, but unfortunately it is not very strong; for example `solve([sin(x) + cos(y) = sqrt(3), sin(x)*cos(y) = 3/4], [x, y])` returns `[]`. I find that `solve([sin(x) + cos(y) = sqrt(3), sin(x)*cos(y) = 3/4], [sin(x), cos(y)])` returns `[[sin(x) = sqrt(3)/2,cos(y) = sqrt(3)/2]]` which is a little more helpful; maybe from there you can get `x` and `y` by hand.

Comment: If you have general questions about Maxima, the mailing list is a good way to get advice; see: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sol: solve([sin(x) + cos(y) = sqrt(3), sin(x)*cos(y) = 3/4], [cos(y),sin(x)]);
solve(sol[1][1],y);
solve(sol[1][2],x);
```

also you can use `to_poly_solve(sol[1][1],y)` to obtain all roots.

Comment: to use ```to_poly_solve()``` function you have first ```load("to_poly_solve")```